# Dialogflow is not giving the proper response

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get a response from firebase function in dialogflow. when I've enabled the webhook and invoking the agent, I'm getting an error as

[image]

and here is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const requst = require('request');
const {
    dialogflow,
    BasicCard,
    BrowseCarousel,
    BrowseCarouselItem,
    Button,
    Carousel,
    Image,
    LinkOutSuggestion,
    List,
    MediaObject,
    Suggestions,
    SimpleResponse,
} = require('actions-on-google');
const intentSuggestions = [
    'Basic Card',
    'Browse Carousel',
    'Carousel',
    'List',
    'Media',
    'Suggestions',
    'Table',
];
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var firestore = admin.firestore();
const randomize = require('randomatic');


exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });
    app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
        conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
            speech: 'Hi there!',
            text: 'Hello there!',
        }));
        conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
            speech: 'I can show you basic cards, lists and carousels ' +
                'as well as suggestions on your phone.',
            text: 'I can show you basic cards, lists and carousels as ' +
                'well as suggestions.',
        }));
        conv.ask(new Suggestions(intentSuggestions));
    });

});
```

Here is the log output in firebase.

[image]

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first error is saying that your billing account is not configured: this will block all external calls in your code. 
You can first try activating billing in Google Console > Navigation Menu > Billing > Enable Billing.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting has nothing to do with billing. The log you have shown is not complete but from your code I can spot the following issues:

- The name of your function must be `dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment` to work with dialogflow.
- Your `const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });` must move out of the `exports` block to somewhere before it.

If there are still issues, please update your question with the complete error log.